# Masters in Space sciences after Aerospace Engineering

Tags: physics, astronomy, career

I'm currently in my first year of Aerospace Engineering and wish to pursue space sciences after graduation. Will I need some extra study in Physics other than my course to be able to successfully pursue masters in space sciences?

Suggestions for colleges for masters are welcome.

Also, any tips for a rookie space enthusiast?

Comment: i feel like theres a better stack

Comment: Pyongyang could be a good Engineering School for you ... seriously: we cannot guess the country you are in, the university you are visiting, the courses you can take ... what for an answer are you expecting?

Comment: Welcome to the site, unfortunately this is not the right place to ask a question of this sort as it is open to opinion and unfocused.

Comment: As noted in previous comments, we do not know where you are, the rules your school has for switching majors, or how graduate schools in your country view taking new students from somewhat related but also somewhat orthogonal undergraduate fields. I'm assuming your current school has advisors. Talk to one of them!